# CSS syncing animation on multiple elements to make one overall animation

Tags: css, animation, ionic-framework, css-animations

I'm making an ionic mobile app, and I'm trying to make the following animation (hopefully through CSS... but I ran into some problems.)

Basically, I want two rows of numbers, 1 2 3 in one row, and 5 6 7 in another.
and I want each number to fade in rapidly to make a countup... with a pause where 4 and 8 would be. (it's for a dance routine)

I tried creating 6 elements and animating each one... but they aren't coordinated. Even when I set them all to the same animation (countAnim1, for example) there's still a coordination issue.  How can I sync them up?

Here's my code: (for brevity, I'll just use 1 2 3)

```css
.left_top {
  margin-left: 10%;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  animation: 2s countAnim1 infinite;
}

.middle_top {
  margin-left: 10%;
  font-size: 2em;
  animation: 2s countAnim2 infinite;
}

.right_top {
  margin-left: 10%;
  font-size: 2.1em;
  animation: 2s countAnim3 infinite;
}

@keyframes countAnim1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes countAnim2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes countAnim3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="left_top">1</span>
  <span class="middle_top">2</span>
  <span class="right_top">3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: you could also use a single  keyframes and animation-delay. setting would be easier to tune ;) https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NYYWZj (not too sure of result expected, so here is the basic idea)

Comment: What do you mean by "not coordinated"? To me, it counts like you said, then pauses, then restarts. Is that not what you want? I then created two rows and then do the same thing though two rows are in step with each other.

Comment: thanks for the replies... I mean that sometimes it's off. I think because the elements are loading at different times?  Sometimes it's right on, but other times it's completely off.  For example, it I set everything just to countAnim1, sometimes every blinks at the same time, and sometimes not.

Comment: I don't see that. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome... but running ionic serve.  Eventually, this goes on a mobile device.

Comment: Holy crap... Thanks G-Cyr!  I got busy researching ionic browser issues, etc. after the response from Rob and didn't take a close look at your code.  You're absolutely right.  that solved the issue.  Thank you!